# Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'cars' for update in FROM clause when using delete query

Tags: mysql

when i use this query in mysql workbench iam getting the below error,

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'cars' for update in FROM clause

i had created and inserted the table and data using the below queries

```sql
create table cars( model_id int primary key,
                   model_name varchar(100),
                   color varchar(100),
                   brand varchar(100)
                 ); 

insert into cars values(1,'Leaf','Black','Nissan'); 
insert into cars values(2,'Leaf', 'Black', 'Nissan'); 
insert into cars values(3,'Model S', 'Black', 'Tesla'); 
insert into cars values(4,'Model X', 'White', 'Tesla');
insert into cars values(5,'Ioniq 5', 'Black', 'Hyundai'); 
insert into cars values(6,'Ioniq 5', 'Black', 'Hyundai'); 
insert into cars values(7,'Ioniq 6', 'White', 'Hyundai');

delete from cars where model_id not in (
  select min(model_id) from cars group by model_name,brand
);
```

please help me

Comment: I removed the image. Please add the code in text form so we can debug it.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in one step but a work around might be to copy it to a temp table do the work there and use the temp table as the ruler in which to measure the update of the table, that way you can update the main table but use the temp table as the selected group values to work around it.

Comment: Other than a tiny performance boost, doing this in two steps isn't a big deal and temp tables can be deleted after use.  Is this too much for you to consider and you abandond the project?  Because my solution would work if you need this to be possible.  Unless you have replication going, this is a good way to do it, if you do have replication, God help you.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your SQL query. This is a limitation of the MySQL engine. For example, the query runs well in PostgreSQL (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pxnyagjb)).

Comment: @easleyfixed A temp table could be a good workaround. However, the OP needs to lock the table while doing so, to avoid *ghost* updates to mess with the data during the interim.

Comment: Yeah if you have multiple users you might want to do that in case someone changes a value in the time frame you try to update it, better safe than sorry.  Although keep in mind that locking can get perma locked if you don't do it correctly and halt your entire application, so look into it before you attempt to use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` before delete query and then `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;` after it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a -- rather obscure -- MySQL syntax that can help you:

```sql
delete cars
from cars
join (
  select model_name, brand, min(model_id) as mid
  from cars
  group by model_name, brand
) x on cars.model_name = x.model_name
   and cars.brand = x.brand
   and cars.model_id <> x.mid;
```

Result:

```
 model_id  model_name  color  brand   
 --------- ----------- ------ ------- 
 1         Leaf        Black  Nissan  
 3         Model S     Black  Tesla   
 4         Model X     White  Tesla   
 5         Ioniq 5     Black  Hyundai 
 7         Ioniq 6     White  Hyundai
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o5VHCZl8).